# multiple labels and checkboxes

Tags: html, label

I wonder what is the right use of  with multiple checkboxes?
I have form style that uses the following scheme to create inline checkboxes:

```
 <label class="checkbox inline" for="???">
        <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="1">1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline" for="???">
        <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="2">2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline" for="???">
        <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="3">3
    </label>
```

It works fine, but I wonder what should I add as "for" attribute for labels? I can also leave it blank, but I would like to know what is the good practice.

Comment: If the input is inside the label, then you should omit the "for" attribute altogether. But I don't think that's what you're really asking since that's irrelevant to whether you've got single or multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Give your inputs unique ids and reference them from your label tags:

```
<label class="checkbox inline" for="option1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="1" id="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline" for="option2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="2" id="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline" for="option3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="highest_grade[]" value="3" id="option3"> 3
</label>
```

Comment: Correct. But we CAN not use `id` and `for` in this case, since the `input` tags are inside the `label` correspondent tag.

Comment: What did I mean is: Yes, we CAN. But it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

##### When the `input` is inside a `label`, there's **no need** to set`for` & `id` attributes

Below is a typical basic setup, where each `label` renders in a new line:

```css
label {
  display: flex;      /* vertically-align the label and the checkbox */
  width: fit-content; /* makes it that only the content is clickable and not the whole row */
  font: 16px Arial;
  gap: 5px;           /* horizontal space between the checkbox and the label */
  margin: 15px 0;     /* vertical space between labels */
  cursor: pointer;    /* nice to have */
  user-select: none;  /* selection looks bad on clickable elements */
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choise-1" value="1">
  Hi
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choise-2" value="2">
  My Name Is
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choise-3" value="3">
  What
</label>
```